# How to concatenate substrings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a column in my dataframe.

It has value in the format :

```
YYYY-Q1
```

I am looking to introduce spaces so that I can join with the master table

Expected format:

```
YYYY - Q1
```

What I have tried:

I tried str.slice and join but it did not work as I was trying to concatenate sub strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try using **str.replace** since you want to replace the **-** with a space. You can try the following

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"Quarter": ["2020-Q1", "2019-Q1", "2020-Q2", "2020-Q4"]})
 df = df['Quarter'].str.replace('-', ' - ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example that I think does what you want:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Quarter": ["2020-Q1", "2020-Q2", "2020-Q3", "2020-Q4"]})
df["Quarter"] = df["Quarter"].apply(lambda _: " - ".join(_.split("-")))
```